# Terraform picks up secrets value from AWS secrets manager in wrong format

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, syntax, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I have a secrets manager secret like:

key: value

```
example: "1.1.1.1/1", "2.2.2.2/2",
```

Now in the plaintext in secrets manager the value shows up like:

```
"\"1.1.1.1/1\", "\"2.2.2.2/2\"",
```

adding these extra `\"` before and after the values.

Now, when I call/get this "value" in terraform it also picks up the same as the plaintext value, which is not acceptable in the code Im calling it in.

```
jsondecode(nonsensitive(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string)).example
```

Can I somehow get the value as is and not with those extra `\"` ??

Comment: Your original value is not json anyway, so that's why it probably does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Marcin is totally right:

> Your original value is not json anyway, so that's why it probably does not work.

You should store your secrets using JSON structure:

```json
{
  "example": ["1.1.1.1/1", "2.2.2.2/2"]
}

OR

{
  "example1": "1.1.1.1/1",
  "example2": "2.2.2.2/1"
}

OR

{
  "example": "1.1.1.1/1, 2.2.2.2/2"
}
```

Get value and simply decode it from JSON to `map(any)`:

```
# 1st JSON
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example     # ["1.1.1.1/1", "2.2.2.2/2"]
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example[0]  # "1.1.1.1/1"
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example[1]  # "2.2.2.2/2"

# 2nd json
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example1  # "1.1.1.1/1"
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example2  # "2.2.2.2/2"

# 3rd json (probably what you want)
jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string).example  # "1.1.1.1/1, 2.2.2.2/2"
```

P.S.: Always remember that Secrets Managers stores your values as plain text. In your case you can store it as a single value `1.1.1.1/1, 2.2.2.2/2` and then you'll get just a string OR you can store it as a JSON string which can be decoded into `map(any)`